# Could someone solve this equation for 0 <x < 1?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Could someone solve this equation for $0 <x < 1$ ?

$$\pi+2\arctan\left( \frac{(1-x^2)\cos(x)+x\sin(x) }{ (1-x^2)\sin(x)-x\cos(x)} \right) -x = 2x \left(\sqrt{1+ \left( \frac{(1-x^2)\cos(x)+x\sin(x) }{ (1-x^2)\sin(x)-x\cos(x) } \right) ^2}\right)^{-1}$$

thanks!

Comment: Ik kan dit met de beste wil niet lezen...

Comment: Haha! Best joke today!

Comment: @user127.0.0.1 Now that's a nice problem to get rid of my today's headache :)

Comment: @imranfat have fun with it :)

Answer (score 2):

This equation has only one root $x=0$ on the segment $[0,1]$, and hence no roots on the
open interval $(0,1)$. To establish this, denote 
$$
y(x)=\frac{(1-x^2)\cos{x}+x\sin{x}}{(1-x^2)\sin{x}-{x\cos{x}}}\,,
\quad z(x)=\arctan{\bigl(y(x)\bigr)},
$$
and notice that $\,z(x)\in \bigl[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\bigr]\;
\forall\,x\in\mathbb{R}\,$. Hence, the equation takes the form
$$
\pi+2z(x)-x=2x\cos{z(x)}.
$$
All you need do is to prove that function
$$
f(x)\overset{def}{=}\pi+2z(x)-x-2x\cos{z(x)}
$$
is strictly deacreasing on the segment $[0,1]$ while $f(0)=0$.